# Variables that contains the color of a text in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, text, colors, write-host

Is it possible to store in a variable the color of a text? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$format1 = "-ForegroundColor White"
$format2 = "-BackgroundColor Black"

Write-Host "Example" $format1 $format2
```

It returns:

```
"Example -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Black" #(not colored)
```

Comment: `$cyan = [System.ConsoleColor]::Cyan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

```
$format1 = @{
    ForegroundColor = "White"
    BackgroundColor = "Black"
}

Write-Host "Example" @format1
```

This method is called [`Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) and basically is how you can pass multiple arguments to a function using a `hashtable`.